# Spark ML Binarizer Example Error

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Binarizer;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

List<Row> data = Arrays.asList(
  RowFactory.create(0, 0.1),
  RowFactory.create(1, 0.8),
  RowFactory.create(2, 0.2)
);
```

Error :
 The result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyRef
       List data=Arrays.asList( RowFactory.create(0, 0.1), RowFactory.create(1, 0.8),RowFactory.create(2, 0.2));

Any pointers ?